# Remove object from the array if the property doesn't exist

Tags: javascript

I have following array of object, I need to remove the object if the property didn't exist

```
const obj = [
  { name: 'Anu', fields: [{ age: 27, data: true }, { age: 17, data: true }] },
  { name: 'Ammu', fields: [{ age: 47, data: true }, { age: 37 }] },
  { name: 'Bat', fields: [{ age: 30 }] },
  { name: 'Asmi', fields: [{ age: 27, data: true }] },
];
```

Expected output

```
const res = [
  { name: 'Anu', fields: [{ age: 27, data: true }, { age: 17, data: true }] },
  { name: 'Ammu', fields: [{ age: 47, data: true }] },
  { name: 'Asmi', fields: [{ age: 27, data: true }] },
];
```

I tried the code but not working

```js
const obj = [{ name: 'Anu', fields: [{ age: 27, data: true }, { age: 17, data: true }] }, { name: 'Ammu', fields: [{ age: 47, data: true }, { age: 37 }] }, { name: 'Bat', fields: [{ age: 30 }] }, { name: 'Asmi', fields: [{ age: 27, data: true }] }, ]

const newArray = obj.filter((ob) => {
  ob.fields.filter((field) => {
    return Object.keys(field).includes("data");
  });
});

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: The outside filter has no Boolean, you do nothing with the internal filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using reduce() method easily. As already someone gave the solution using the reduce() method. I did different way using map() and filter() method. You can try this. Thank you

```
const obj = [
            {name: 'Anu',fields: [{ age: 27, data: true },{ age: 17, data: true }]},
            { name: 'Ammu', fields: [{ age: 47, data: true }, { age: 37 }] },
            { name: 'Bat', fields: [{ age: 30 }] },
            { name: 'Asmi', fields: [{ age: 27, data: true }] },
        ];

    
        let newArray = obj.map((item) => {
                let fields;
                let f = item.fields.filter((a) => a.data);
                if (f.length > 0) {
                    fields = f;
                }
                return { ...item, fields };
            }).filter((f) => f.fields);

        console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
obj = [{ name: 'Anu', fields: [{ age: 27, data: true }, { age: 17, data: true }] }, { name: 'Ammu', fields: [{ age: 47, data: true }, { age: 37 }] }, { name: 'Bat', fields: [{ age: 30 }] }, { name: 'Asmi', fields: [{ age: 27, data: true }] }, ]

console.log(
    obj.filter(x => x.fields.find(y => y.data)).map(a => ({...a, fields: a.fields.filter(b => b.data)}))
)
```

Comment: object `Ammu` not fullfilled

Comment: Looked very promising, but you still have a `{
        "age": 37
      }` in there

Comment: @mplungjan you were right. i have updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the result set by filtering out items that have no valid fields.

For the items that are valid, you just filter their fields based on whether the `data` property is present and `true`.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'Anu'  , fields: [ {age: 27, data: true}, {age: 17, data: true} ] },
  { name: 'Ammu' , fields: [ {age: 47, data: true}, {age: 37} ] },
  { name: 'Bat'  , fields: [ {age: 30} ] },
  { name: 'Asmi' , fields: [ {age: 27, data: true} ] },
];

console.log(arr.reduce((res, item) => 
  ((fields) => fields.length ? [ ...res, { ...item, fields } ] : res)
  (item.fields.filter(field => field.data))
, []));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduce()`

```js
const obj = [{ name: 'Anu', fields: [{ age: 27, data: true }, { age: 17, data: true }] }, { name: 'Ammu', fields: [{ age: 47, data: true }, { age: 37 }] }, { name: 'Bat', fields: [{ age: 30 }] }, { name: 'Asmi', fields: [{ age: 27, data: true }] }, ]

const newArray = obj.reduce((a, ob) => {
  let fields = ob.fields.filter(i => i.data)
  let obj = {...ob, fields}
  return fields.length ? [...a, obj]: a
}, []);

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use the below code:

```js
obj = obj.filter(item => item.fields.find(field => field.data));
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
     const obj = [{ name: 'Anu', fields: [{ age: 27, data: true }, { age: 17, data: true }] }, { name: 'Ammu', fields: [{ age: 47, data: true }, { age: 37 }] }, { name: 'Bat', fields: [{ age: 30 }] }, { name: 'Asmi', fields: [{ age: 27, data: true }] }, ]

    const newArray = obj.filter((ob) => {
        let newFields = ob.fields.filter((field) =>     Object.keys(field).includes('data'));
        if (newFields.length > 0) {
            ob.fields = newFields;
            return true;
        }
    });

    console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Where did ammu go?

Comment: its now there. but honestly, use the reduce() function as others stated

Comment: You do not need an else after a return